# Find optimal estimator for exponential distributions.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Consider $X_{1} \dots X_{n}$ are **i.r.v** with $Exp(\theta)$ ($p_{\theta} = \theta e^{-\theta x}$). We want to find optimal estimator of $\theta$ (i.e. unbiased estimator with minimal variance in unbiased estimator class).

Our teacher tells us that it can be done with using sufficient and completeness statistics.

It's easy to determine that $X_{(1)}$ is satisfy this properties. Now we want to make it unbiased.

We need to find some $f(x)$, such as : $\mathbb{E}(f(X_{(1)}) = \theta$.

That is a problem moment. Actually I'm thinking that there is no such functions.

I've tried to consider some easy examples : $f(x) = x^{m}, f(x) = \log{x}$ and $f(x) = e^{x}$ but it give's me only $\theta^{a}$ ,where $a \ne 1$ or functions like $\frac{\theta^{m}}{\theta^{2} + const}$ .

Any hint's will be good .

Comment: Please define 'optimal estimator'. Looks like you are talking about UMVUE. And by $Exp(\theta)$, what is the form of the pdf you mean to specify?

Comment: @StubbornAtom added

Comment: Then $\sum X_i$ rather than $X_{(1)}$ is a complete sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom yes, I agree with that

Comment: So if you are familiar with Lehmann-Scheffe theorem, find $E(1/T)$ where $T=\sum X_i$ has a Gamma distribution and hence find an unbiased estimator of $\theta$ based on $T$. This unbiased estimator is the optimal estimator you are looking for.